# Excel: Using an IF() Function with Conditions Depending on Other Cells

Tags: excel, if-statement, spreadsheet

I am writing an excel script for my company, and I am getting hung up on something. I have written a formula that calculates pay for a certain benefits we have.

This paragraph explains parts of the spreadsheet that work. If the employee was here for at least a year, they receive their benefit. If not, they are not eligible. I have a column that has a condition for their eligibility using the IF() function and determines whether or not they are eligible by their hire date. I also have a column that says the total pay from their benefit (6 percent of their normal hourly rate multiplied by their hours worked).

The issue I need help with is the last separate column that determines their pay if they are in fact eligible. What I want to do, is if the eligibility is true, have the cell display their benefit pay. If they are not eligible, I want the cell to display 0 (I already have a column saying if they are eligible or not to prevent confusion).

The formula I currently have looks like this:

```
=IF(V2="Eligible for SWW Pay",=T2,=0)
```

where V is the eligibility column and T is the pay given from their benefits. The formulas in both T and V give the correct output. However, this formula for the last column gives me an error. I don't know if it is a syntax error or if my logic is totally wrong for doing this.

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong? Any feedback is greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: Please include the error.

Answer (score 1):

I would propose you the following formula:

```
=IF(V2="Eligible for SWW Pay",T2,0)
```

The equal-signs in front of `T2` and `0` are not needed.